# Weird result from lm function in R

Tags: regression, linear-model

I have some data, linked here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rGgny-SZHzkjwj7xTSuEbLEhvx_JoVraG3udWqk-zN0/edit?usp=sharing

I tried to do a simple `lm`. My code is:

```
testLM <- lm(formula=No~ScoreMA, data=MA.df)
```

The results I observed are 1.653e-02 for the variable (p-val <2e-16) and 1.479e+01 for the intercept (p-val <2e-16).

This is an impossible result because from the plot, it is quite clear that the gradient should be positive and the data is quite good linearly speaking. I tried to use online tools and it is proved. I attached the picture. What's wrong with my R code? Thank you. [image]

Comment: The result shows a positive slope.  There's nothing wrong.  The -02 is part of exponential notation.

Comment: The result is different from the online tools. The slope is not positive, it is almost zero, 0.001. We can see the result from the online tools is ~56. It seems I ordered the variable wrong. After I switch the formula, it shows the correct and same result as the online tools.

Answer (score 5):

You made an elementary mistake. When you used lm() in R you regressed X on Y instead of Y on X.

Comment: The crux of question was more towards the confusion regarding scientific notation as @PeterFlom mentioned in the comments.